# decypher with me that obfuscated MultiplierFactory

Tags: python, obfuscation, python-datamodel

This week on comp.lang.python, an "interesting" piece of code was [posted](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.python/msg/fbd486398fcff81b) by Steven D'Aprano as a joke answer to an homework question. Here it is:

```
class MultiplierFactory(object):
    def __init__(self, factor=1):
        self.__factor = factor
    @property
    def factor(self):
        return getattr(self, '_%s__factor' % self.__class__.__name__)
    def __call__(self, factor=None):
        if not factor is not None is True:
            factor = self.factor
        class Multiplier(object):
            def __init__(self, factor=None):
                self.__factor = factor
            @property
            def factor(self):
                return getattr(self,
                '_%s__factor' % self.__class__.__name__)
            def __call__(self, n):
                return self.factor*n
        Multiplier.__init__.im_func.func_defaults = (factor,)
        return Multiplier(factor)

twice = MultiplierFactory(2)()
```

We know that `twice` is an equivalent to the answer:

```
def twice(x):
    return 2*x
```

From the names `Multiplier` and `MultiplierFactory` we get an idea of what's the code doing, but we're not sure of the exact internals. Let's simplify it first.

### Logic

```
if not factor is not None is True:
    factor = self.factor
```

`not factor is not None is True` is equivalent to `not factor is not None`, which is also `factor is None`. Result:

```
if factor is None:
    factor = self.factor
```

Until now, that was easy :)

### Attribute access

Another interesting point is the curious `factor` accessor.

```
def factor(self):
    return getattr(self, '_%s__factor' % self.__class__.__name__)
```

During initialization of `MultiplierFactory`, `self.__factor` is set. But later on, the code accesses `self.factor`.

It then seems that:

```
getattr(self, '_%s__factor' % self.__class__.__name__)
```

Is doing exactly "`self.__factor`".

***Can we always access attributes in this fashion?***

```
def mygetattr(self, attr):
    return getattr(self, '_%s%s' % (self.__class__.__name__, attr))
```

### Dynamically changing function signatures

Anyway, at this point, here is the simplified code:

```
class MultiplierFactory(object):
    def __init__(self, factor=1):
        self.factor = factor
    def __call__(self, factor=None):
        if factor is None:
            factor = self.factor
        class Multiplier(object):
            def __init__(self, factor=None):
                self.factor = factor
            def __call__(self, n):
                return self.factor*n
        Multiplier.__init__.im_func.func_defaults = (factor,)
        return Multiplier(factor)

twice = MultiplierFactory(2)()
```

Code is almost clean now. The only puzzling line, maybe, would be:

```
Multiplier.__init__.im_func.func_defaults = (factor,)
```

What's in there? I looked at the [datamodel doc](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy), and found that `func_defaults` was "*A tuple containing default argument values for those arguments that have defaults, or None if no arguments have a default value*". ***Are we just changing the default value for* `factor` *argument in* `__init__` *here?*** Resulting code would then be:

```
class MultiplierFactory(object):
    def __init__(self, factor=1):
        self.factor = factor
    def __call__(self, factor=None):
        if factor is None:
            factor = self.factor
        class Multiplier(object):
            def __init__(self, innerfactor=factor):
                self.factor = innerfactor
            def __call__(self, n):
                return self.factor*n
        return Multiplier(factor)

twice = MultiplierFactory(2)()
```

Which means that dynamically setting the default value was just useless noise, since `Multiplier` is never called without a default parameter, ***right***?

And we could probably simplify it to:

```
class MultiplierFactory(object):
    def __init__(self, factor=1):
        self.factor = factor
    def __call__(self, factor=None):
        if factor is None:
            factor = self.factor
        def my_multiplier(n):
            return factor*n
        return my_multiplier

twice = MultiplierFactory(2)() # similar to MultiplierFactory()(2)
```

Correct?

*And for those hurrying to "this is not a real question"... read again, my questions are in bold+italic*

Comment: Ummm... You seem to want to treat Stackoverflow as a discussion forum. That's not going to work out so well...

Comment: afaik, there are two clear questions, on private accessors and dynamic signature changes. What else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1. Can we always access attributes in this fashion?

A: No. It's only those attributes who start with double underscores. They get obfuscated in that way, to prevent accidental access/overriding from outside the class.

Q2: Are we just changing the default value for factor argument in `__init__` here?

A: Yes.

Q2: right?

Right.